# How to override MuiTouchRipple-root css

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to make my select list scrollable on horizontal because the text is too long and the user cannot see it entirely

I saw that I can succeed to make it if I change the `overflow` css property in `MuiTouchRipple-root` but I don't how I can access to it for overriding this property

I checked the doc of the component `<MenuItem>` and it doesn't seems like I can access to `MuiTouchRipple` I think I have to pass by `<ListItem>` but I dont want to use it.

Here is an example of select field where I would apply (I don't think the value of each state matter so I didn't put it), then you can see how I usually change the style of my component

```
     <TextField
        id="outlined-select-currency"
        select
        disabled={this.state.isDisablePhone}
        label={msg}
        className="telecom_phone-list"
        value={this.state.phone_selected}
        name="phone_selected"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        SelectProps={{
          MenuProps: {
            className: classes.menu,
          },
        }}
        margin="normal"
        InputProps={{ classes: { root: classes.root, notchedOutline: classes.input } }}
        variant="outlined"
       >
        <MenuItem value={'none'} classes={{ root: classes.root }}Choose your phone></MenuItem>
        {this.state.res_list.map((data, key) => (
           <MenuItem classes={{ root: classes.root }} key={key} value={data}>
             {data.product_name} - {data.search_price} €
           </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To override MuiTouchRipple, you can use this approach.

```
TouchRippleProps={{ classes: { child: 'my-class' }}}
```

Hope this will help